# Java - showing splash screen while application performs setup

Tags: java, splash-screen

I'm writing a program using Java and I need to use a splash screen to let the user know that the application is starting. I have tested how long the application is to set up using the following code:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
frame = new CFSMainFrame(); // main app
long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
System.out.println("Total time: " + ((float)totalTime/1000) + " seconds!");
```

and it returns a total time of **2.66 seconds** in average. I want to show a splash screen during this time. I have looked around and even checked the splash-screen API, but I don't find it very "noob"-friendly and was wondering if someone in here could give me a very simple example for showing an image during this time, there is no need for a fancy loading bar or anything..

Comment: if you want something simple, just create new frame with a label like "Loading..." before calling `new CFSMainFrame` and close it right after instanciation is completed.

Comment: Check out [how to create a splash screen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html)

Comment: @Vince I have tried that already . No success. I don't know what I might be doing wrong but running `SplashDemo demo = new SplashDemo();` does absolutely nothing for me.

@ortis I will try that. Thanks!

Comment: @Zeliax You didn't read the tutorial. That's not what the tutorial said to do

Comment: @VinceEmigh I tried doing what the tutorial said. Running the `java -splash:images/splash.gif SplashDemo` very briefly shows the splash image, (for less than ½ a second) and no window appears for me to close. Besides I'm already running my application by running the following command `java -Dlog4j.configuration=resources/log4j.properties -jar CFSSupportTool.jar` and I don't know how to add the splash screen image to that command..